# Acessing Struct variables from Conway's Life

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I wrote the code for Conway's Game of life in Java, and now I'm trying to convert it to C. The code is pretty straight-forward, however I'm having trouble trying to create the appropriate `struct`.

In Java, if I had the `instance variables`:

```
 private boolean[][] board;
 private boolean[][] nextBoard;
```

Would it be equivalent to the following code?

```
 struct generation
 {
    char **board;
    char **nextBoard;

 }generation;
```

How would I access these variables from another method? I think it would be something like this, but I'm not sure:

```
 struct generation data;
 .....
 data.nextBoard[r][c]
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with java, so tell me, how will `board` and `nextBoard` from your java exmple behave: do you need to define sizes of dimensions? can you use tham as they are without any initialization?

Comment: For instance variables in Java, you just initialize the type and name like shown, and the create them, (in this case create the size) in the instance methods of a class. And then every time that method is called from the main method, it will update the variables.

Comment: C doesn't have anything like Java arrays. It would be simplest to set the array dimension at compile-time and use `char board[R][C];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the *access method* of `data.nextBoard[r][c]` is correct, but, `nextBoard` and `board` being pointer type variables, you need to allocate memory to them before using.

Maybe you can look into [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family of functions to get the memory allocation done.

---

EDIT: if you don't want dynamic memory allocation, consider chaging the structure definition to

```
#define SIZ 64     //some arbitrary value

struct generation
 {
    char board[SIZ][SIZ];
    char nextBoard[SIZ][SIZ];

 };
```

and you can access from index `0` to `63` directly in aforesaid way.

Comment: Is there another way to do this without using `malloc()`? We haven't learned that yet.

Comment: @kris you can use fixed-size arrays as long as you know the desired size at compile-time.

Comment: @kris Well, in case of pointer, you have to use `malloc()`. Otherwise, you can consider changing the type of `nextBoard` and `board` to a pre-decided array. That'll  also work.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, I think I'll use a pre-defined array then, thanks! Would it be better for me to use a `typedef` `struct`?

Comment: @kris See, usage of `typedef` depends on personal choice. It's an option, if you feel `typedef` will make your code better readable, use it. if you feel otherwise, no one will force you. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh well I wouldn't grab any "arbitrary value" to serve as my precious array size, but other than that it's fine :)

Comment: @Quentin Ha ha, that's just to tell, "you can use any value you want". Thanks for the review sir, BTW. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't take this the wrong way, but, your Java is showing. 
I C/C++ (as you may very well know), you don't have a garbage collector; so you have to take care of the memory management.

It looks like you need memory for two matrices. You can allocate that a few ways:

1. static allocation (you won't have to worry about memory leaks):

   char board[N][M];

   char nextBoard[N][M];
2. dynamic allocation (you need to remember to free the allocated memory):

   - allocate one contiguous memory block of size N*M:

     char *board = malloc(sizeof(char)* N * M)

     char *newBoard = malloc(sizeof(char) * N * M)
   - allocate memory using a pointer to pointer:

     char **board;

     char **newBoard;

     Here you have to allocate memory for the rows and columns separately (I won't go into too much detail about it as the info is widely available).

Now whether you package them into a struct, you keep the global, or you restrict their visibility to a certain file (using static), is really the decision you have to make here.

Either way you do it, you can access the elements int the array using row/column indexes. Even in the case of a one dimensional array (board[r+c]).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I definitely need all the improvement recommendations that I can get, I'm definitely going to use static allocation this time.